# Rendering Multiple Viewports using GLUT

Tags: user-interface, opengl, glut

Using OpenGL and GLUT, I want to render a scene from two different viewpoints. For the first viewpoint, it is a standard perspective projection using shaders. For the second viewpoint, it is a visualisation of the depth buffer. I want these two images to be contained within the same window, side-by-side.

So far, I have been using GLUT for display. For example, I use:

```
glutInitWindowSize(1000, 1000);
glutInitWindowPosition(500, 200);
glutCreateWindow("OpenGL Test");
```

This will draw my scene across the entire window for the one viewport which I have defined. But can I use GLUT to draw two different images from two different viewports, as described above? Or perhaps this is not so easy with just GLUT, and I will need to create a window natively in my operating system (I am using Ubuntu), and then define two different areas in that window which I should draw upon...

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GLUT ultimately has nothing to do with it. It creates and manages a window. What you do *within* that window is entirely up to you.

What you need to do is use the [viewport transform](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Viewport_Transform). Because the viewport happens after clipping, no primitives outside of the range of the viewport transform will be rendered to (by [drawing commands](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Drawing_Command). Buffer clearing will still clear the whole framebuffer). This effectively defines the region of the window that all vertices will lie within.

So you call `glViewport`, specifying half of the window. Then you render the stuff you want in that half. Then you call `glViewport` to specify the other half. Then you render the stuff you want there. And then you're done; just swap buffers.

However, this also means that the typical tactic of only calling `glViewport` in your GLUT resize callback will not work. You must *store* the window's current size, then use that in your display function.

Comment: Thanks. In fact, I also want to be able to register mouse callbacks which are specific to the individual subwindows. I don't think that `glViewport()` can do this, but I've come across `glutCreateSubWindow()` which might help me...

Comment: @Karnivaurus: Wouldn't it be easier to just check which region the mouse is clicked within? It's a point-in-rectangle test; it's not even hard.

Comment: Good idea, much easier haha! I'm not sure what use `glutCreateSubWindow()` has then, perhaps if you are doing something much more complicated than what I'm proposing...

Answer (score 1):

Two ways you can do this:

- You can create a new window with `glutCreateWindow()`.  Note that this will have a different OpenGL context.  Also note that it has a return value, an integer.
- You can select part of the window using `glViewport()`, and then call `glViewport()` again to draw into a different part of the same window.

Answer (score 0):

There is always the option of rendering your two views into a single texture, and then simply making a screen size quad and rendering that texture onto your quad.

I'm not sure its going to satisfy all your needs, but from a visual perspective this should give you the same result.